# Automatic acronyms of strings in R

Tags: string, r, parsing

Long strings in plots aren't always attractive. What's the shortest way of making an acronym in R? E.g., "Hello world" to "HW", and preferably to have unique acronyms.

There's function `abbreviate`, but it just removes some letters from the phrase, instead of taking first letters of each word.

Comment: How do you propose dealing with duplicated abbreviations?

Comment: @AnandaMahto Perhaps by adding a second letter, like "Hello World" → "HeW" if "HW" is occupied?

Comment: @Anton adding second letter is really bad idea as it may lead to lots recursive loops.

Comment: @ChinmayPatil, `abbreviate` should be able to handle it OK though, but if you look at the code for the function, it's a lot more involved than either of our answers :-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An easy way would be to use a combination of `strsplit`, `substr`, and `make.unique`.

Here's an example function that can be written:

```
makeInitials <- function(charVec) {
  make.unique(vapply(strsplit(toupper(charVec), " "), 
                     function(x) paste(substr(x, 1, 1), collapse = ""), 
                     vector("character", 1L)))
}
```

Test it out:

```
X <- c("Hello World", "Home Work", "holidays with children", "Hello Europe")
makeInitials(X)
# [1] "HW"   "HW.1" "HWC"  "HE"
```

---

That said, I do think that `abbreviate` should suffice, if you use some of its arguments:

```
abbreviate(X, minlength=1)
#            Hello World              Home Work holidays with children           Hello Europe 
#                  "HlW"                  "HmW"                  "hwc"                   "HE"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using regex you can do following. The regex pattern `((?<=\\s).|^.)` looks for any letter followed by space or first letter of the string. Then we just `paste` resulting vectors using `collapse` argument to get first letter based acronym. And as Ananda suggested, if you want to make unique pass the result through `make.unique`.

```
X <- c("Hello World", "Home Work", "holidays with children")
sapply(regmatches(X, gregexpr(pattern = "((?<=\\s).|^.)", text = X, perl = T)), paste, collapse = ".")
## [1] "H.W"   "H.W"   "h.w.c"

# If you want to make unique
make.unique(sapply(regmatches(X, gregexpr(pattern = "((?<=\\s).|^.)", text = X, perl = T)), paste, collapse = "."))
## [1] "H.W"   "H.W.1" "h.w.c"
```